# Sql Server Union All dont get all rows

Tags: sql-server, union, except

Simple question about SQL Server.

I expected that this query:

```
-- part 1    
select * from table01
except
select * from table02
--
union all
-- part 2
select * from table02
except
select * from table01
```

would give me the same result set as if doing the two part 1 and part 2 separately. But I just get two rows from the query but two rows from both of the parts. Would be interesting to know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Declare @t table(col1 int)
insert into @t values(1),(2)

Declare @t1 table(col1 int)
insert into @t1 values(1),(3)

1.)  select * from @t
      except
2.)  select * from @t1
       union all
3)    select * from @t1
      except
4)    select * from @t


1 ) and 2 ) give 2
then previos result aand 3 gives 2,1,3
then again last result and 4) give 3
so final Result=3
```

Comment: Thank you. But what I should have written is
(select * from peter01
 except
 select * from peter02)
union all
(select * from peter02
 except
 select * from peter01)

Answer (score 3):

`except` contains an implicit `distinct` for both inputs. Probably, you did not expect that. Without concrete example data it is hard to tell what exactly happened.

```
SELECT name FROM sys.objects
EXCEPT
SELECT name FROM sys.objects WHERE 0=1
```

Is equivalent to

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM sys.objects
```

Both have the same execution plan (including a distinct).